# DataGridView + C#

Tags: c#, ооп

**Здравствуйте!**

На форме находится элемент DataGridView с двумя колонками (тип колонок - DataGridViewTextBoxColumn , и на форме соответственно галочки).

**Подскажите пожалуйста, как отследить, поставлена ли галочка?**

Пробую код:

```
if (((System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView)(sender)).CurrentCell.Value == true)
{
     //галка стоит 
}
```

пишет ошибку - нельзя сравниваит поля разных типов: object и bool.
Как исправить ?

Answer (score 3):

```
if ((bool)((System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView)(sender)).CurrentCell.Value == true)
```

но вообще почему DataGridViewTextBoxColumn  должен быть булом?
и что значит и "на форме соответственно галочки" ?

Comment: Я ошибся - спасибо что заметили.
Тип колонок: DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn а не (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)

Comment: Заработал следующий варинт:

Convert.ToBoolean(((System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView)(sender)).CurrentCell.Value)

Спасибо Чад за подсказку.